# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - SINK - How to configure partition file size

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, partition

I am copying blob avro files from azure blob to azure data lake.
I created a DataFlow and I have three partition columns: grid_id, _year, _month
In the Sink-Optimize tab "Set partitioning"  I choose "Key" and set these columns.
So the file structure is: grid_id/year/month

The problem is the files generated "part-xxxx" are smaller to 1mb. Is there any way to configure it?

I tried to merge rows to a single partition file but it is not what we want.

Comment: provide the screen shot for you Dataflow for better understanding.
Also refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance

Answer (score 0):

I posted [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1354152/how-to-configure-partition-key-file-size?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1306870) in MS forums:

Seems that there is no way to configure partition Key file sizes. We can increase file size by reducing the number of partitions.